# What does `Failed to promote during pruning` mean exactly? Why might one be seeing that in their node logs?

Tags: log, pruning

Seems to rise from `substrate/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/base_pool.rs` but there's a lot going on there.

Why might this warning be hit? How can it be resolved?